# Why use a multiplexer the select from GND and VCC instead of an Inverter?

Tags: vhdl, ethernet, vivado

I have created a VHDL module that generates a one-bit wide pattern of "1010101010..." continuously, as long as an input signal called "start" is asserted high. This is the elaborated circuit design produced by Xilinx Vivado v2014.4 (64-bit, Linux):

[image: Elaborated Circuit]

**The Question**

What is the purpose of the "next_state_i" multiplexer? It seems like a simple inverter between Q and D would be a simpler design. Is there an advantage to using a multiplexer instead of an inverter?

**The Code**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity TASK2_PRE is
    Port ( clock, start : in STD_LOGIC;
           data_out     : out STD_LOGIC);
end TASK2_PRE;

architecture Behavioral of TASK2_PRE is

    signal current_state    : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal next_state       : STD_LOGIC := '0';

begin

    -- no need to decode current state - map FFs directly to outputs
    data_out <= current_state;

    -- decode next state
    next_state_decode : process(current_state, start)

    begin

        if (start = '0') then
            next_state <= '0';

        elsif (current_state = '0') then
            next_state <= '1';

        else
            next_state <= '0';

        end if;

    end process next_state_decode;

    -- update current state
    update : process(clock)
    begin

        if (clock'event AND clock = '1') then
            current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process update;

end Behavioral;
```

Note: I know the state-machine approach is a bit heavy-handed just to generate this pattern, but implementing this behavior as a FSM was a requirement of this project for a class.

Comment: A single-process SM would be considerably less heavy handed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram is a literal representation of your code — `if - else - end if` in VHDL source code maps directly to a multiplexer in the hardware. No optimization has been performed.

If you were to synthesize this logic for an FPGA, both muxes would be implemented inside a single LUT (lookup table) that drives the input to the FF.

Answer (score 2):

If you were building a specific dedicated function from individual logic gates, then an inverter would be a good choice.

If you are targeting a design at an FPGA, then you have to use the components that the FPGA provides. The manufacturer makes all the components to be as versatile as possible, because they need to be able to be configured to do anything. As a mux can do the job of an inverter, but an inverter can't do the job of a mux, then a mux is what Vivado gets to build the logic from.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when code like the following generates a multiplexer in the schematic (Vivado 2017.1):

```
foo: process(clk) is
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (somesignal = '0') then
            ..
        end if;
    end if;
end process foo;
```

I can have the design place an inverter instead of a multiplexer by first assigning the inverse to another signal then using that inverted signal testing for '1' instead:

```
not_somesignal <= not somesignal;

foo: process(clk) is
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (not_somesignal = '1') then
            ...
        end if;
    end if;
end process foo;
```

The multiplexer won't always be eliminated (in the schematic check that the mux indeed only has VCC and GND inputs) and sometimes unrolling into combinational expressions works better when the logic needed only needs to combine one or two minterms/maxterms (combining with or/and as appropriate).

Comment: my core design to mimic a 6502 is hitting this frequently due to all the active low signals found on that processor chip